# Prove $x^n=x^m $ if and only if $m\equiv n \pmod{k}$ in a finite group generated by $x$ of order $k$

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $G$ be a finite group generated by $<x>$ of order $k$, given $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ then prove that
> $x^m=x^m$ if and only if $m \equiv n \pmod{k}$

*My attempt*
Suposse that $x^n=x^m$, then let $x^{m-n}=x^mx^{-n}=x^{n}x^{-n}=e$  therefore
$k|m-n$ and  $m \equiv n \pmod{k}$

For the converse suposse  $m \equiv n \pmod{k}$ and consider
$x^{m-n}=x^{m}x^{-n}=e$ and $x^{-n+m}=x^{-n}x^{m}=e$ that implies
$(x^{-n})^{-1}=x^{m}$ it is $x^{m}=x^{n}$

Comment: good observation

Comment: now I fix my proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is fine, if you are comfortable with that $x^n=e\implies o(x)|n$.

The converse seems a little messy.  There are a couple things, actually.  If you are using multiplicative notation, then why are you using $0$ for the identity?  Also, to simplify, you can just write $m=n+kl$.  Then you simply have $x^mx^{-n}=x^{n+kl}x^{-n}=x^{kl}=(x^k)^l=1^l=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks, I upgrade my proof , and I read you proof and i conclude that both are similar.

Comment: I still don't see where you use $m\equiv n\bmod k$, for the converse.

Comment: I'm use it when I say $x^{m-n} =e$ Iff  $k|m-n$

Comment: But, and I'm referring to the second part, you don't use it in the proof.  I would try to incorporate it.